# GRAILS GORM how to update a parent property automatically when saving a child

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I have two objects.

```
TimeFrame{

  hasMany=[activity:Activity]

   Date startTime
   Date endTime
   Integer activeActivities
```

}

```
Activity{
   belongsTo=[timeFrame:TimeFrame]

  String name
  String description
  Date start
  Date end

}
```

Anytime I insert,update, or delete an Activity I want to automatically update the number of activeActivities a timeframe has. But when I add GROM event methods like...

```
def afterUpdate(){
    try{

        def num=0;
        def now=new Date();
        timeFrame.activities.each{i->
            if(!i.end || i.end < now){
                num+=1;
            }
        }
        timeFrame.activeActivities=num;
        timeFrame.save();
    }
    catch(e){
        log.debug('Unable to update active tally on Activity update:'+e)
    }
}
```

I get the error

```
  null id in com.application.tracker.Activity entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs).
```

What's a way around this?

Comment: You're save inside `afterUpdate` is failing because you aren't using `withNewSession`. See the documentation: http://docs.grails.org/2.4.x/guide/GORM.html#eventsAutoTimestamping

Comment: aha. Critical sentence... "Fortunately the withNewSession method lets you share the same transactional JDBC connection even though you're using a different underlying Session"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why your `save` is failing inside your `afterUpdate` is because you aren't using `withNewSession`. The [documentation](http://docs.grails.org/2.4.x/guide/GORM.html#eventsAutoTimestamping) points out this detail.

> Notice the usage of withNewSession method above. Since events are
>   triggered whilst Hibernate is flushing using persistence methods like
>   `save()` and `delete()` won't result in objects being saved unless you run
>   your operations with a new Session.
>
> Fortunately the withNewSession method lets you share the same
>   transactional JDBC connection even though you're using a different
>   underlying Session.